# how to run run --history-api-fallback inside of webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-v4

```js
let path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    entry:path.resolve('public/src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path:__dirname + "/public",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader:'babel-loader',
            query:{
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    },
    watch:true
};
```

I am using reactjs router and in tutorials, they majority tell you to write

--history-api-fallback for the router to work

```js
let path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    entry:path.resolve('public/src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path:__dirname + "/public",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader:'babel-loader',
            query:{
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    },
    watch:true
};
```

```css
{
  "name": "pr_v1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js & webpack",

    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "request": "^2.82.0",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import Reducer from './Reducer/';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

import App from './Components/App.jsx';







const store = createStore(Reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));


 

ReactDOM.render(

     <Router history={browserHistory}>
         <Route path='/user' component={App}/>
     </Router>

    ,document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am new to react-router and i am trying to get the --history-api-fallback to work. Tutorials say to put it in the build of the json file, but i do not have a build script. I am thinking that maybe it should be somewhere is the webpack config file. I am not sure. My question is where can i insert --history-api-fallback so that it works.

Answer (score -1):

For webpack dev sever, you just need to add webpack dev config. This is going to work in your dev environment.

```
devServer: 
{
  historyApiFallback: true
},
```

Comment: Ok, So where exacly would i write that piece of code in?

Comment: in module.exports of your webpack config